# Finding top n rows for each partition in Hive

Tags: hive, hql, partition-by

I tried something like

```
select * from table_name
group by column1
Order by column2 desc;
```

But it doesn't work because you ought to put all selected columns in group by statement.

Is there something like

```
for each partition
*do something*
```

In hive ?
Thanks.

Edit: the column1 is the column over which partition is made

Answer (score 0):

We generally use `ROW_NUMBER()` for such cases.

```
SELECT a.col1
    ,a.col2
    ,a.col3  --Other columns
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY column1
    ORDER BY column2 DESC
    ) AS rn
FROM table_name t ) a
WHERE rn >= n -- filter based on rn to get top n rows for each partition.
```